# Unable to call the parent method in react-native

Tags: react-native

I need to call the method nameList(). It is the parent method. But it not worked for me. My code snipppet is below.

Below is my code snippet refer and any answer should be appreciated. I need the clarification about this

```
nameList = refName => () => {
if(!nameList){
   get call
 }
else(){
   update call
 }
}

renderNamesRight(selectedName) {
    if (selectedNames.length > 0 ) {
      return(
        this.renderCenterNames()
      )
  }
}

renderCenterNames(){
    if (!this.state.pressedCenterNames) {
      return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=> this.validateInputFields()} activeOpacity = { .5 }>
          <Text style = {styles.names}>CENTER NAMES</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    } else {
      return(
          <Text style = {styles.names}>RIGHT  NAMES</Text>
      )
    }
  }


validateInputFields() {
     const { validation} = this.state;

     if (this.state.name) {
       alert("validation")
       validation.isFormValid = true;
       this.setState({validation: validation});
       this.nameList("name")
    } else {

      validation.isFormValid = false;

      this.setState({validation: validation});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This not the way you define a function. If you need a function with no parameter you have to define like this `FunctionName = () => {}` or with parameters `FunctionName = (parameters) => {}`.

If there is only one parameter in a function you can also declare it without  **( )** like this `FunctionName = parameter => {}`

Replace your method definition

`nameList = refName => () => {`

with this

```
 nameList = (refName) => {
```

Comment: I have a clarification if I pass the refName as a parametr it not worked. Why?